# Supersort - Sort multiple variables together

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-supersort

I'm trying to sort my commerce orders by 2 variables, one being in the order loop, and the second being within the lineitems. I want to order by the lineitem variable first, and THEN the order variable. Something a bit like this:

Order - Group Name
LineItem - Product ID

I want to order by custom product ID asc and then Group Name alphabetically. So it would go a little like this:

ID: 1, GroupName: Aaa
ID: 1, GroupName: Bbb
ID: 2, GroupName: Aab

etc...

The current code I have is this:

```
{% set orders = craft.orders().limit(null).all() %}
{% set orders = orders|supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.groupName }}') %}

{% for order in orders %}
    {% for item in order.lineItems %}
       {{ item.purchasable.product.customProductId }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally, I'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
{% set orders = orders|supersort('sortAs', '{{ item.purchasable.product.customProductId }} {{ object.groupName }}') %}
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do this by putting it all into an array:

```
{% set productID = [] %}
{% set orders = craft.orders().limit(null).all() %}

{% for order in orders %}
    {% for item in order.lineItems %}
        {% set productID = productID |merge([ {
            'productId' : item.purchasable.product.customProductId,
            'groupName' : order.groupName
        }]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% set productID = productID | supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.productId }} {{ object.groupName }}') %}

{% for theID in productID %}
    {{ theID.groupName }} - {{ theID.productId }}
{% endfor %}
```